# Nginx stops automatically at particular time

Tags: nginx

I am facing a strange issue where nginx stops/crashes at around 12am(12am-1am) and 12pm(12pm-1pm) everyday UTC time. I am monitoring(up/down) a website using a website monitoring tool. When website is down, at the same time there is an entry in nginx error log:

```
2018/07/02 12:16:54 [notice] 2288#2288: signal process started
```

When I check nginx status using "sudo systemctl nginx status" it says:

```
Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2018-07-02 12:16:54 UTC; 19min ago
```

So, I have to restart nginx to make the website working and again the same thing happens next day.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue myself. I checked syslogs and it was certbot that was trying to renew certificate at a particular time. Fixing certbot fixed the issue.

Comment: You should add the steps you took in order to figure out the problem, might help someone else in the future.